# SQL Entity referenced by many other entities - best practice

Tags: sql, jpa, foreign-keys, one-to-many

I'm currently working in an environment using a relational database and jpa, where a big entity holding `Parameter` entities gets transformed through a lot of steps.
Each step converts the big entity into another, while the `Parameter` entities move around and get referenced by other entities.
Each step is persisted.

In all situations only exactly one entity of a kind references a collection of `Parameters`, so there are mostly `OneToMany` relations.
This means the `Parameter` table has a lot of foreign keys, currently there are about 8 foreign keys which feels a lot like bad practice.

Are there best practices for entities which get referenced by a lot of other entities to prevent one table in the relational database to contain too many foreign keys?

Example:
The `Parameter` is a class, we use to represent, to generate forms in the backend to tell the frontend "This is a text-field", "This is a number-field", "This is a dropdown, allowing values from A to Z".
It looks like this:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Parameter {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  //Enum
  private ParameterType type;
}
```

This means, there are `Form` classes:

```
public class Form{
 
  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name="parameterId")
  private List<Parameter> parameters

}
```

Like `Form` there are `Table` and other input mechanics, all holding a list of `Parameter`, so just imagine about 7 more classes all having the attribute

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="parameterId")
private List<Parameter> parameters;
```

My problem now is, that the Database Table for `Parameter` is a table with 11 columns of which only 3 are values of `Parameter`, the other 8 are foreign keys.
There is no technical problem, I'm just asking if this is a Bad Practice and if there are better ways to do this.

Comment: Some sample data would really help illustrate what you are asking.  I'm not sure what "too many foreign keys" means.  Are you running into some sort of limit?

Comment: There are no technical problems, I'm just concerned a table with many foreign keys is bad practice